# In autocomplete mode(combobox) suggested items is not complete

Tags: c#, combobox, autocomplete

I am using ComboBox to show email-Id list. I have used the Dropdown style.
For suggestion I have used AutoComplete mode.

Problem : All results will showing at the time of suggesting items(type some starting keys).

Here code snippet :

```
  'AutoCompleteStringCollection combData = new  AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    combData.AddRange(ComboItems);

    combo.AutoCompleteCustomSource = combData;
    combo.Sorted = true;

    combo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    combo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;

   m_cmbNode.DropDown += (sender, e) => m_cmbNode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None; m_cmbNode.DropDownClosed += (sender, e) =>         m_cmbNode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;'
```

Comment: We could identify your problem.. can you explain us?

Comment: Yes Sure.. 
All Items not getting populate at the time of suggestions.

Comment: In the list contains abtest2@gmail.com, but I type 'ab' then ab get populate the starting with 'ab' but 'abtest2@gmail.com' will not get populate.

Comment: Can you see this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AutoCompletion02012006113508AM/AutoCompletion.aspx

Comment: I think Textbox is enough for this concept..

Comment: This is not working in my case, But may be textbox is enough.

Comment: Actually code does not have any problem. Their is some special characters so after that it ignores remaining items.   Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using some special characters in the list items, I am unable to identify the exact characters, so that it is missed last items from list.